# Rendering Problems: class could not be instantiated: - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I recently changed over to Android Studio from Eclipse and when starting new projects with a blank activity template have come across the following message in my main layout xml file

[image]

I looked up SO and tried the following solutions:

*Raising the minSDK in the build.gradle file - it raised additional problems of missing styles

*Trying to update Android Studio - I was up-to-date even in the "Canary" setting

*Reducing the API level of the layout - when I went down to API 22, the image disappeared altogether.

In Eclipse, I would go to Properties/Android and see if anything needed to be updated, or go to Build Path to see if it looked OK.

What can I do here? Thanks:)

Comment: Does it persist or does it go after a short while? I often get the latter and think it might just be Studio catching up on everything. Does the same with java code. Especially when starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found an answer on SO that worked for me. (I am sorry but I haven't figured out how to quote the question no.)

> I also got this problem today,
>
> Check your build.gradle file, do you use support design lib version
>   23.2, like
>
> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0' if so, change it to
>   version 23.1.0
>
> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0' then rebuild your
>   project... seems version 23.2 is still buggy